# fix the column width in .txt file using c++

Tags: c++, fstream, filehandle

i have created one class of doctor and i want to insert data of doctor in note pad file (Doctor.txt) but data do not have a symmetry because there is no fixed length of my inputs in the line...

```
        int DocID;
        string Name,Department,Specification,Address,PhNo ;
        Doctor D;
        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open ("Doctor.txt",ios::app);
          cout<<"please enter doctor ID: ";
          cin>> DocID;
          cout<<"please enter doctor Name: ";
          cin>> Name;
          cout<<"please enter doctor Department name: ";
          cin>> Department;
          cout<<"please enter doctor specification: ";
          cin>> Specification;
          cout<<"please enter doctor Address: ";
          cin>> Address;
          cout<<"please enter doctor Phone Number: ";
          cin>> PhNo;

          D.set_data(DocID,Name,Department,Specification,Address,PhNo);
          myfile <<endl<<D.get_DocID()<<"  "<<D.get_Name()<<" "<<D.get_Department()<<" "<<D.get_Specification()<<" "<<D.get_Address()<<" "<<D.get_PhNo();
          myfile.close();
```

how can i generate a symmetrical   .txt file using fixed width of columns of inputs

Comment: If you Doctor.txt file is long, than it may not be a good practice to read each entry in it, reformat entry and write it again. So, if I were you my main problem wouldn't be fixed-length entries. It would be "what if the doctor name has a space in his/her name?" because you use space to separate variables. That causes confusion.

Comment: "Use basic maths" comes to mind .. though you may also wish to look into I/O Manipulators. jnbrq has a point, though - you probably ought to render proper, well-formed CSV instead if you want your format to be of any actual practical use.

Comment: @jnbrq-CanberkSönmez, how the spaces would be handled?.. I think it would be better to introduce "-" in place of spaces between the entries.

Comment: You might use <iomanip>. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436004/how-do-i-correctly-organize-output-into-columns). It already addresses your problem.

Comment: @AwaisMahmood There are some non-printable characters, such as "\a". Those character will be possibly not given for any kind of data field. So you may consider using them instead of space.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [setw](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/) width manipulator function provided by `<iomanip>` header file and using it before or after or however you want to write each entry to the file.